# Alternative to git clone inside the Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I want to use the softlink (symlink) of an already cloned git repository instead of the git clone in  Dockerfile.

I am currently using the cloning the i to clone the mosquitto-go-auth repo in the mosquitto dockerfile like this:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth.git
WORKDIR mosquitto-go-auth
<do stuff>
```

But, now I need to modify some code in the mosquitto-go-auth repo.
So, I cloned the mosquitto-go-auth repository outside the repository where the dockerfile is present.

How can I create a softlink of another repository in my current repository so that, I can replace the git clone and use softlink of locally cloned repository in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

Just map the directory containing the repository at run time using a volume.

For example, if your repo is in a folder named `$HOME/git/mosquitto-go-auth`

`docker run -v $HOME/git/mosquitto-go-auth:/mosquitto-go-auth ...`